# Always getting blank page while using php and mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql

I am always getting blank page when using Php and mysql connections

- [this is my php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOvL3.png)
- [this is my html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaQ3B.png)

Comment: Do not paste code as images please.

Comment: To add to Norrius' comment, instead of using images please paste your code directly into your question. Then you can select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to indent it by four spaces, which will cause SO to treat it as code.

Comment: You should add some error checking, it may not be able to connect to db. Avoid using root user, and also read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) before going any further.

Comment: You should get some information from logs, or you can change the settings to make PHP display the error messages on your page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```